# How is a Kilofactory (Megafactory, Gigafactory) better than a normal Factory?

Tags: factory-idle

The game allows you to purchase additional factories with increasing multiplier in names.

How are they different from the starting one? Does a Kilofactory generate 1000 times the income as a starting factory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**, it does not have any multipliers or advantages.

Sadly, a Kilofactory is just an another location with more workshops to purchase. Even worse, all your Upgrades (purchased for money, not Research) are factory-specific and will have to be re-bought.

Note: *there is no reason to hold back, though. Plot B0 (starting workshop in Kilofactory) has much better value than plot A8 that you might be saving for at that time.*